# Mysql Update and Select first element

Tags: mysql

i use two requests :

```
SELECT `user` FROM `table1` ORDER BY `last activity` ASC LIMIT 0,1;
```

and

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `last activity` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `user` = 'user'
```

I would like to join both in only one request.. Because two program take often the same user.

EDIT: I forgot to say I need the user name, so only UPDATE the first element is not enough. I would like take the user with the last activity, update the time, and my program do something with this user. The problem is that many programs are running simultaneously. And it is important not they access the same user at the same time between two requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html).

That would look something like this:

```
UPDATE `table1` 
    SET `last activity` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE `user` = (SELECT `user` FROM `table1`
        ORDER BY `last activity` ASC LIMIT 0,1)
```

Comment: can't select from the same table you are updating

Comment: Oh right, forgot about that for a second. Wouldn't it be possible if you'd give the tables aliases (`table AS t1`)?

Comment: not for the subquery.  Update join might work haven't tried